# Modify Content-Disposition or Content-Type headers with Mule message-properties-transformer

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, mule

My outbound `jaxws-client` message has no content disposition set.

If I try to add before the outbound endpoint with:

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="Content-Disposition" value="somevalue"/>
</message-properties-transformer>

<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="12.34.56.78" port="1234" path="services/SOAP/Tests" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="testConnector" responseTimeout="50000" >
    <cxf:jaxws-client 
        clientClass="com.test.Service"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="true"
        operation="getTest"
        port="Test"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/test.wsdl">

        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:bean id="cxfIn" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors> 
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean id="cxfOut" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
</https:outbound-endpoint>
```

the Content-Disposition is not added to the message. However, when I add a character to the name, e.g. `-Content-Disposition` instead of `Content-Disposition`, the value is added:

```
DEBUG 2013-11-06 12:54:53,286 [[muletest].header.stage1.02] httpclient.wire.header: >> "-Content-Disposition: somevalue[\r][\n]"
```

The same happens for `Content-Type` header which is already present in the original message. I also cannot delete it with `<delete-message-property>`. Are they somehow protected from modification?

How can I add or modify those headers?

Comment: Please add you Outbound configuration  here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

Rmeove the message properties transformer.

```
       <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />

<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="12.34.56.78" port="1234" path="services/SOAP/Tests" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="testConnector" responseTimeout="50000" >
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Disposition" value="somevalue"></set-property>
    <cxf:jaxws-client 
        clientClass="com.test.Service"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="true"
        operation="getTest"
        port="Test"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/test.wsdl">
                    <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:bean id="cxfIn" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors> 
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean id="cxfOut" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
</https:outbound-endpoint>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work because `set-property` is not a valid child of `cxf:jaxws-client`.

Comment: Adding the element under the `outbound-endpoint` results in the same behaviour: if it is called `Content-Disposition` it will not be available, if it's named differently (e.g. `--Content-Disposition`), it will be available.

Comment: I have been using the set-property to set the Content-Type of my HTTP outbound. It is working. Not sure why it is not wokring in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this right before your `https:outbound-endpoint`

```
   <set-property propertyName="contentType" value="text/html" /> <!-- Set it to whatever you'd want -->
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
 <http:outbound-endpoint ref="serverEndpoint" contentType="application/x-download">
            <properties>
                <spring:entry key="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=foo.zip"/>
                <spring:entry key="Content-Type" value="application/x-download"/>
            </properties>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>
```

[Reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-http/3.3.0-RC2/http-headers-config-flow.xml)

Comment: This results in the same behavior as when using the `message-properties-transformer` or putting the `set-property` inside the https endpoint. The header will not be visible if it is some standard header like `Content-Disposition` or `Content-Type`

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot see `Content-Disposition` or `Content-Type` properties in the log, so you're not sure that these properties got updated or not

Comment: A `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor`is defined inside the `cxf:outInterceptors` node. It logs the outbound message in a format similar to the one provided in my original question: `DEBUG 2013-11-06 12:54:53,286 ...`. It will not show the `Content-Disposition` nor the changes made to the `Content-Type`, but it will show `<someString>Content-Disposition` header. I believe that Mule overwrites the changed headers with what it believes they should be, but I might be wrong. Do you think that the properties are there, just not logged?

Comment: Did you try using the `flow-Analyzer` for `MMC` to see all properties. Its a great tool for debugging but its only available in enterprise edition. http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Analyzing+Flow+Processing+and+Payloads